# How to inspect all alarms defined in the AlarmManager on the system?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I suspect there are applications on my Android system that use the AlarmManager way too agressively (eg. exact repeating, instead of inexact repeating, etc.).  Is there a way to inspect all alarms set in the AlarmManager on the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you get alarms in the output of `adb shell dumpsys`, though the information may be a bit difficult to decipher.

Comment: You can limit the other stuff from dumpsys by calling dumpsys alarm